# Elasticsearch how search in multiple fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, elasticsearch

I am using **elasticsearch 1.2.1** and I want to do a **search from javascript with several fields**, for instance, by title and content.

My code is:

```
 var data = { q: 'title: test};         
 $.ajax({
     data:  data,
     url: http://localhost:9200/_search,
     type:  'GET',
     success: function (data) {
         $.each(data.hits.hits, function(position,hit) {
            $("#<portlet:namespace/>search-pattern").append( '<li>' + hit._source.title + '</li>' );
         });
     }
 });
```

But in addition to **search for a title also** want to look for the **content field**.

What should be the value for the attribute data in order to search not only by the field 'title' but also by the field 'content'?

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Request Body Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-query.html), specify the conditions using [Query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html)

Comment: More specifically, you have several ways to perform a full-text search in multiple fields at once, but the easiest is to use a  [**multi_match**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#query-dsl-multi-match-query) query